# Dynamic git config user.name - depend on hostname

Tags: git, dynamic, config

I use `git` from two computers.

I would like to:

- Use the same `~/.gitconfig` file on the two computers.
- Have different `user.name` on commits from one computer or the other.

In short, I'd like to be able to have something like **`user.name = "Mic - #{Hostname}"`**, with `Hostname` being dynamically read.

**Is there a way to achieve this?**

The only other way I see would be to manually change the `user.name` on each git repo I use on those 2 computers - but I don't find it clean.

---

**Solution for those in this situation**:
There seems to be no built-in solution as git does not auto-expand config parameters. So, following the advice below, I just issue the following command in my deploying script after importing a new (shared) `~/.gitconfig`:

```
git config --global user.name "Mic [`hostname`]"
```

That way, git name is always updated.

Depending on your config, you can also put that in your `~/.bashrc` or whatever `~/bash_profile` you use - although it looks a bit overkill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git does not to variable expansion in the config file.

To do this you could add a line to your .profile or whatever startup file you are using to call

```
git config --global user.name ${GIT_USER_NAME}
git config --global user.email ${GIT_USER_EMAIL}
```

and have those set prior to calling this.

Answer (score 4):

Do not store name in `~/.gitconfig` but in your `~/.bash_profile` set environment variables:

```
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="Mic - $HOSTNAME"
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME"
export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME GIT_COMMITTER_NAME
```